# Beginner certification to enter into project management

Tags: prince2, capm

I am looking for project management entry level certification. I searched online and I found CAPM and PRINCE 2. I am bit confused which one should I go for.  Which one is worth doing??

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 articles that describe the differences so that you can to make sensible choices.

1. [Should I take CAPM or PRINCE2?](https://www.girlsguidetopm.com/should-i-take-capm-or-prince2/)
2. [PMP vs CAPM vs PRINCE2 - Which One's Right for you?](https://www.whizlabs.com/blog/pmp-capm-prince2/) and you can see that you have a third choice also of PMP.

I think a summary would be the quote:

> The main difference between CAPM/PMP and PRINCE2 Foundation/Practitioner is project experience. Having said that, it’s not compulsory to have project management experience under your belt for CAPM, as long as you can demonstrate 23 hours of formal project training instead. There are no pre-requisites for applying for the PRINCE2 exams (although it will be certainly easier to understand the concepts if you have spent at least some time working on projects).
>
> Because PMI requires pre-requisites either in the form of training or work experience and PRINCE2 doesn’t, I don’t think they are seen as equivalent (or competing, for that matter).

And there is  the issue of cost - both are a similar price.

Also, CAPM certification expires after 5 years and you have to do it again, but PRINCE2 is forever.